# Is there a way to position unordered lists (<ul>) next to each other

Tags: html, html-lists

I'm new to HTML and apologize if this has been asked before (but I couldn't find a previous post). I am working on a website and am trying to position several lists next to each other instead of below each other, but am having trouble accomplishing this. I have included my code below, and please let me know if you need additional lines.

```
<!-- Resume Skills -->
                <div>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-gears"></i>           
                 <p><br><i><b><i style="font-size:20px" class="col-md-4 .col-md-offset-0";</i>Job Skills</b><br></i></p>
                  <ul><i>
                  <li>One</li>
                  <li>Two</li>
                  <li>Three</li>
                  <li>Four</li>
                  <li>Five</li>
                  <li>Six</li>
                  <li>Seven</li></i>
                 </ul>
                </div>     
                <!-- Areas of Interest -->
                <div>
                <i class="fa-brands fa-hubspot"></i>            
                 <p><br><i><b><i style="font-size:20px" class="col-md-4";</i>Areas of Interests</b><br></i></p>
                  <ul><i>
                  <li>Carpentry</li>
                  <li>Welding</li>
                  <li>Electrical</li>
                  <li>General Contracting</li>
                  <li>Management</li>
                  <li>Logistical Support</li>
                  <li>Accounting</li></i>
                 </ul>
                <div>
```

Comment: You would change the formatting of your HTML with CSS. Please include the CSS you're using so we can see what the issue is. This should work though: `ul { display: flex; flex-direction: row; }`

Comment: Oh ok. I apologize but I haven't looked at the css file before, it came in a bootstrap folder. Do you know roughly where in the css file I would look or should I upload the entire css script? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you open up the Chrome developer tools and inspect the elements with classes, you should see the CSS rules applied to the classes. You can Google “Bootstrap display children side by side” and find classes you could apply to your HTML to make the items display side by side.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion it's very helpful! I am going to read through the search results from Googling "Bootstrap display children side by side". Thank you again!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Run it through the validator and fix those 24 errors first.

Answer (score 1):

flex is an option the other option could be grid.

I  write an example

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p> 1 </p>
  <p> 2 </p>
  <p> 3 </p>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Adding style to ul can simply solve the problem.
`ul {display:flex; flex-direction: row}`

Here's the sample code

```
<style>
   ul {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
   }
   li {
     margin-left: 20px;
     list-style-type: none;
   }
</style>
<body>
    <div>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-gears"></i>           
       <p><br><i><b><i style="font-size:20px" class="col-md-4 .col-md-offset-0";</i>Job Skills</b><br></i></p>
        <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
        <li>Six</li>
        <li>Seven</li>
       </ul>
      </div>     
      <!-- Areas of Interest -->
      <div>
      <i class="fa-brands fa-hubspot"></i>            
       <p><br><i><b><i style="font-size:20px" class="col-md-4";</i>Areas of Interests</b><br></i></p>
        <ul>
        <li>Carpentry</li>
        <li>Welding</li>
        <li>Electrical</li>
        <li>General Contracting</li>
        <li>Management</li>
        <li>Logistical Support</li>
        <li>Accounting</li>
       </ul>
      <div>
  </body>
```

[image]